# How to choose the best logit model using step function in R

Tags: r, model, logistic, goodness-of-fit

I have the data below.

[image]

I was wondering how I could choose the best model fit of logit model using `step` function in R. Here is the data in R format:

```
dose <- c(1.6907, 1.7242, 1.7552, 1.7842, 1.8113, 1.8369, 1.8610,1.8839)
number <- c(59,60,62,56,63,59,62,60)
dead <- c(6,13,18,28,52,53,61,60)
y <- dead/number
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to step through model specifications because you only have one independent variable and one dependent variable.

```
model <- glm(cbind(dead,number-dead)~dose,family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

Comment: If you analyze the data, you will see that the best model is the quadratic model: $logit(\pi_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \beta_2 x_i^2 $. How would I had known that without comparing models?

Comment: Forgive me, but you didn't include any basis expansions as a part of your "data," so I think it's a bit unfair to expect me to anticipate that. If your question had included a bit more information and context, I would have been able to provide a more complete answer. Given the three sentences you wrote, it appeared to me that you were having difficulty understanding what the use case of `step` is.